# Array to TableView (Xcode 3.2.6)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, xcode3.2

I have an NSMutableArray of data that i would like to present in a view,

how might someone go about doing this?

i have seen that the best way to present Array data is by displaying it onto a table, but cannot find anything that can help someone using Xcode 3.2.6, as it lacks some of the functionality that later versions have.

Any ideas?

Comment: i am almost completely new to this language, so would appreciate something basic, although something more difficult would still be very useful!

Comment: Side note - why are you using an ancient version of Xcode? You won't be able to use it to submit any apps to Apple. It also means you are learning lots of out-of-date features and functionality and you are missing out on all of the new features of iOS and Objective-C.

Comment: Why would you want to use a software that was presented 4 years ago?

Comment: If you are completely new to Cocoa Touch I recommend working through some tutorials as it will help enormously: http://www.raywenderlich.com

Comment: @rmaddy i am using this as i am a student and cannot afford to pay for a newer laptop, and it makes sense to get someone kind of idea of what im doing before spending all of that money, does it not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the best way is to use a UITableView.

Have a look to [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/)

Comment: And then pop this in to convert your mutable array to an NSArray (NSMutableArrays cannot be data sources): `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`